# How can I get the last day of the current month with DateTime?

Tags: perl, datetime

My task is to calculate the last day of the current month.

There is a method `last_day_of_month` in [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime). You can call it like this:

```
$av_tmp_TODAY = DateTime->last_day_of_month({year=>2016,month=>05});
```

But I do not want to set a fixed year and month, I just want to take today's date and get the last day in that month.

In addition, I want my output in the format `%Y-%m-%d`.

Answer (score 8):

You use the constructor `now()` and then the output method `ymd('-')` together with the desired separator. If not specified, it's `-` by default.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw{say};
use DateTime;

my $dt = DateTime->now();
say DateTime->last_day_of_month( year => $dt->year, month => $dt->month )->ymd('-');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ perl -MDateTime -wE 'say DateTime->today
                                   ->set_day(1)
                                   ->add(months => 1)
                                   ->subtract(days => 1)
                                   ->ymd'
```

Output:

```
2016-05-31
```

Answer (score 1):

Learn the `perldoc` command.

`perldoc DateTime` should tell you that `$dt = DateTime->now;` will get you an object with the current date and time, from which you can extract the current year and month with

```
$year   = $dt->year;
$month  = $dt->month;
```

You will also find there

```
$ymd    = $dt->ymd;           # 2002-12-06
$ymd    = $dt->ymd('/');      # 2002/12/06
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the day, month, and year, you should use [`localtime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html):

```
my($day, $month, $year)=(localtime)[3,4,5];
```

To then get the last day of the month, use your code from above:

```
$av_tmp_TODAY = DateTime->last_day_of_month({
    year  => $year + 1900,
    month => $month +1
})->ymd('-');
```

Note: You must add 1 to `$month` and 1900 to `$year` to get the correct month and year. This is shown in the example above.

For further reading on this topic, see:

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=2158

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Sorry, I just added another line of code to substitute the values into the last_day_of_month method.